# predict() method in R gives inconsistent results

Tags: r, svm

I am using KSVM of `kernlab` to predict future values. After generating the model `predict()` method is used to get the future values.

The code is listed below:

```
data=read.csv('D:\\MyData.csv')
forecastInterval=2000
col=2

dataLength=length(data[,1])
plot(data[,col],xlim=c(0,8000),ylim=c(-200,200), type='l')
svmX=seq(1,dataLength,1)
regm <- ksvm(svmX,data[,col],type='eps- bsvr',kernel='anovadot',epsilon=0.5,kpar="automatic",cross=3)
newSvmX=seq(dataLength+1, dataLength+forecastInterval,1)
predict=predict(regm,newdata=data.frame(newSvmX))

lines(newSvmX,predict,col="green")
lines(seq(1,dataLength+forecastInterval,1),predict(regm,seq(1,dataLength+forecastInterval,1)), col='blue')
```

Here the CSV file consists of two columns: First column consists of time stamps, Second column consists of CPU utilization. Based on this data I need to predict future CPU utilization.

The issue I am facing is that the starting values of `predict` variable start at:

```
              [,1]

   [1,] -151.68668

   [2,] -151.65964

   [3,] -151.63247

   [4,] -151.60518

   [5,] -151.57776

   ...   ...   ...
```

while the last value of actual data is `8.462130`, due to this there is a break in the graph of actual data and predicted values.

Another issue is that when I draw lines using

```
lines(newSvmX,predict,col="green")
```

then this 'green' line is disconnected from actual data. While if I use:

```
lines(seq(1,dataLength+forecastInterval,1),predict(regm,seq(1,dataLength+forecastInterval,1)), col='blue')
```

then this 'blue' line is continuous with original data.

kindly help me with this issue that why the values given by `predict()` method are not in continuation with original data and why the two 'lines()' method operating on same data produce different graphs.

Attached is the screenshot of the graph.
[image: Imange displays the different behavior of same <code>regm</code> variable for different prediction ranges]

Thanks

Comment: The lines don't match up because you're using different values for the `x`-values. I can't tell because you didn't provide the source data, but probably you're generating extrapolated values way outside your dataset--always a risky move.   BTW, don't name your variables (`predict`) the same as functions.  That will lead to trouble.

Comment: @ Carl Witthoft: Thanks for your response. So does it mean that starting point of `x`-values must always be from 1 instead of ending of black graph, because both the graphs (blue and green) are giving predictions for same range but their predicted values are different. Also the predictions of blue graph seem to be more consistent. However if the training data is very large (as is my case) then taking values from 1 causes `ksvm()` method to take very long time to compute. Kindly suggest which method to follow for prediction in such a case (blue graph method or green one).

Comment: I can't tell - you need to make sure that you are accessing the correct component of your `predict` variable (. I don't know the class of `regm` as produced by `kvsm` but in all likelihood you need to specify which list element or matrix component of `predict` you want to plot in your green-line plot call.